# Ruby on Rails 6 with Minitest: Is there a way to shorten the outputted error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, minitest

I'm going through Section 3.3 of *The Ruby on Rails Tutorial* by Michael Hartl and we just started the section on testing. In this section, we're grouping static pages in a controller (StaticPagesController) and are trying manually to add an "about" action to the controller. Because we are practicing TDD, we are writing a failing test first. However, the outputted error message is extremely long (I don't know if this is standard), and I want to know if there is a way to shorten the output. Thanks in advance!

**test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb**: we write the following code (two previous and passing tests omitted for brevity):

```
require "test_helper"

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

I then run the following command in the terminal to run the tests:

```
% rails test
```

As expected, the output to the terminal shows 1 error. However, the error is extremely long (so long that it does not fit in the VS Code terminal -- I have to view it in the system terminal) and I have to scroll up hundreds of lines to see the start of the offending error.

**Sample of Error**:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError: NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_about_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fefbd442320 @_routes=nil, @NAME="test_should_get_about", @failures=[#<Minitest::UnexpectedError: Unexpected exception>], @assertions=0, @integration_session=#<#<Class:0x00007fefbd441c40>:0x00007fefbd4414c0 @_routes=nil, @app=#<SampleApp::Application:0x00007fefbd2fc308 @_all_autoload_paths=["/Users/christophermarchant/Documents/odin-project/full-stack-ruby/rails-course/hartl_rails_tutorial/sample_app/environment/sample_app/app/channels", "/Users/christophermarchant/Documents/odin-project/full-stack-ruby/rails-course/hartl_rails_tutorial/sample_app/environment/sample_app/app/controllers", ... @stubs=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00007fefbcd08550 entries=0 default_proc=#<Proc:0x00007fefbcd084b0 /Users/christophermarchant/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.5/lib/active_support/testing/time_helpers.rb:14>>>, @time=0.12419799994677305>
```

The entire error is much longer.

It appears that Rails is inspecting and printing the entire StaticPagesControllerTest object with all of its attributes.

**MAIN QUESTION: Is there a way to change some configuration so the NameError is shorter, like the following?**

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_about_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00007fefbd442320>
```

**OTHER INFO**

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '3.0.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.5'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '>= 4.0.0.rc1'
  gem 'webdrivers', '~> 5.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.5'
  gem 'minitest', '~> 5.15'
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'guard', '~> 2.18'
  gem 'guard-minitest', '~> 2.4', '>= 2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.4'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**test/test_helper.rb file**:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative "../config/environment"
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/reporters"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Run tests in parallel with specified workers
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end

Minitest::Reporters.use!(
  Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new(:color => true),
  ENV,
  Minitest.backtrace_filter
)
```

**System and Versions**:

Ruby on Rails 6.1.5

Ruby 3.0.3p157

macOS Big Sur Version 11.6.4

Comment: Thats not a failure message - its a stack trace since the test is blowing up. Shortening the stack trace is really just shooting the messenger and will bite you in the bum later when you have to deal with more complex errors.  A better way to actually test this would be to use `get '/about'` instead of using the route helper from the test. That would give you a "red" test which fails because the route is not defined instead of the test itself blowing up because its calling an undefined method.

Comment: If you should use route helpers in your integration tests is a somewhat controversial topic - but in this case where the route takes no arguments its just silly. The book doesn't really seem to explain the difference between a broken and failing test either. A broken test raises an uncaught exception and doesn't even run to completion. A failing test runs but the assertion does not pass.

Comment: Not a stack trace, but rather, what the author said. In rails I routinely get megabyte long error messages because of method_missing errors, as it inspects the instance to an arbitrary length.